# MQTT client for j2ME

Tags: java-me, mqtt

I want to use MQTT client with J2ME application. I could not find any clients available in http://mqtt.org/software. Please let me know if there are any open source clients readily available for J2Me. If not how to move forward.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please let me know if Eclipse Paho MQTT client supports J2ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Paho MQTT client doesn't currently support J2ME. There is a recent thread about this on the paho-dev mailing list, including the hint that it should be fairly straightforward to port:

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/paho-dev/threads.html#00059